# Build operation failed without specifying any errors when adding Swift Unit tests to projects

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I'm currently working on an objective c project where we are trying to now incorporate swift into the project. When I add a Swift unit test to the project I get the following prompt:

[image]

I create the bridging header. However, when I try to run my tests I keep getting the following error:

> Build operation failed without specifying any errors. Individual build
> tasks may have failed for unknown reasons. One possible cause is if
> there are too many (possibly zombie) processes; in this case,
> rebooting may fix the problem. Some individual build task failures (up
> to 12) may be listed below.

I've googled for the error and most people say restart the simulator, xcode, your machine etc. I've done all of this. The problem seems to lie in using swift inside of my unit tests.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your project closer to your root directory.  Swift compiler can have issues with reaching ARG_MAX in large projects.

https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-compilation-reaching-arg-max-limit-causing-xcode-build-failure/6494